# NodeJS regex pattern not matching expected cases

Tags: node.js, regex, web-scraping

I'm working on a nodeJS server that's expected to find email addresses and must use regex to do so.

I'm using the following pattern:

```
/[A-Z0-9.]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}([A-Z]{2,})?/i
```

And I'm expecting it to match the example email. This is a real snippet from a scraped website, just anonymized.

```
      <a href="mailto:user@a.foo.edu">user@a.foo.edu</a>
```

To do this, I'm using the builtin [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function like so:

```
let expr = /[A-Z0-9.]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}([A-Z]{2,})?/i
let str = "<a href="mailto:user@a.foo.edu">user@a.foo.edu</a>"
console.log(str.match(expr));
```

I'm expecting the output to be an array of matches, but instead get `null`. Note that in the server, `str` is the full HTML of a webpage scraped with [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) and converted with `toString()`. It works [in this Regexr example](https://regexr.com/3hqee) I created.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

**Solution**

I'm not sure why my original approach did not work. In the end, creating a RegExp object worked for me like so:

```
let expression = "[A-Z0-9.]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}([A-Z]{2,})?"
let regexp = new RegExp(expression, 'ig');
let results = bodyText.match(regexp);
```

However, I could not get it to function without creating an object first.

Comment: If you define the `str` correctly, you will get `[  "user@a.foo.edu",  "user@a.foo.edu"]` as a result. At any rate, to match `.`, you need to escape it outside a character class (the `.` after `+` must be escaped).

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I tried the regex you provided in Ruby and it worked after I removed the `g` from the end, and put parenthesis around the first part: http://rubular.com/r/0SVySpQCZg

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I actually do have it escaped, but didn't reflect it in my post. I'll update it.

@evanrelf Thanks for the suggestion. I've played around with flags, but I'm still ending up with `null`.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Omitting the case-invariant flag makes the regex not match for obvious reasons. Please provide a [mcve] with your actual regex and no syntax errors

Comment: At the very least, you need to either include lowercase letters `a-z`, or add the case insensitive flag `I`. But your expression is way too restrictive for many e-mail adresses. A quick Google search will surely yield much better regexes.

Comment: It should have had an invariant flag. I've been screwing around with flags for awhile and lost track. However, no combination of flags yields anything but `null`.

Comment: You must double escape the `.`: `"[A-Z0-9.]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,}([A-Z]{2,})?"`

Answer (score 0):

Add `g` to end of your regex

```
let expr = /[A-Z0-9.]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}([A-Z]{2,})?/ig
let str = "<a href="mailto:user@a.foo.edu">user@a.foo.edu</a>"
console.log(str.match(expr));
```

**RegExp Flags**

> `g`
>   global match; find all matches rather than stopping after the first match
>   `i`
>           ignore case
>       `m`
>           multiline; treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each
>   line (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of
>   the whole input string)
>       `u`
>           unicode; treat pattern as a sequence of unicode code points
>       `y`
>           sticky; matches only from the index indicated by the lastIndex property of this regular expression in the target string (and does not
>   attempt to match from any later indexes).

take a look to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)